# Html form not calling the action

Tags: php, html

I have a form that opens in a modal. 
And the submit is not working, it is not calling the action.

I have set the method post, and action is supposed to call a php file.
However, it isnt working at all.

Here is the code, and you can test it here:

http://mentores.in/comprar.html

[image]

Click in "comprar" to open the modal.

```html
<section id="first-step" class="wc-billing-step">
  <div class="woocommerce-billing-step-one">
    <h4>
      Dados do Participante
    </h4>
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="enviar_inscricao.php">
      <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome do participante">
      <input type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF">
      <input type="text" name="nasc" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" onkeyup="
       var date = this.value;
       if (date.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
          this.value = date + '-';
       } else if (date.match(/^\d{2}\-\d{2}$/) !== null) {
          this.value = date + '-';
       }" maxlength="10">
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
      <input type="text" name="celular" placeholder="Celular">
      <input type="text" name="end" placeholder="Endereço">
      <input type="text" name="cid" placeholder="Cidade">
      <input type="text" name="esta" placeholder="Estado">
      <input type="text" name="cep" placeholder="CEP">
      <p>Caso seja menor de idade</p>
      <input type="text" name="resp" placeholder="Nome do responsável">
      <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Telefone">
      <p>Caso o pagamento seja em nome de terceiro</p>
      <input type="text" name="pagseg" placeholder="Nome do titular do cartão">
      <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Produtores"> -->
      <select type="text" name="indi" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Quem te indicou?">
        <option value="Escolha">Escolha uma opção</option>
        <option value="Marcelo Caldas">Marcelo Caldas</option>
        <option value="Nenhum desses">Nenhum desses</option>
      </select>




      <input class="price-btn subm" type="submit" name="submit-form" value="Continuar" id="accept" />

    </form>

  </div>
</section>
```

I need that form to call the php page in the action.

Comment: Can you send us the `enviar_inscricao.php`?

Comment: There is too little to work with here

Comment: Button in snippet is working fine. Looks like there are some javascript blocking the button click action. Maybe `preventDefault` or `return false;`. Take a look relevant scripts?

Comment: Bruno, when you hit the submit button, what happens? Do you see a 404, does the page not change at all?

I would expect you to go to the URL of "enviar_inscricao.php".

In your snippet, we see a 404 becaus there's no PHP file in that location.

Comment: can you send a screenshot of the folder structure?

Comment: Shane, the page does not change at all, you can check it on the real page at the link I posted.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does your browser's network console show some more insights?

Comment: It doesn't show anything, that's why I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @BrunoDeFaria It does call the PHP page; you can see that in the browser's Network console. (Right click anywhere, hit 'Inspect', move over to 'Network'.) Your PHP page is triggered with an AJAX/XHR request. In your javascript, you need to watch out for that request completing.

Answer (score 0):

You had defined an on click behaviour on `price-btn` to open the modal.

```
$('.price-btn').on('click', function(e) {
```

So you need to be more specific with your selectors because your Form hast the same selector.

Comment: There's no sign of that in the question. If the problem only appears on an external website, then the question should be closed as it lacks a [mcve].

Comment: Yes you can see this on the website it self

Comment: Yes, that's true. I took it off, so it is not overlaying the modal. Thanks.

But still no calling the action.

Comment: If you have a look into the devtools you will see that there is an POST will be send to the /enviar_inscricao.php (the result is an empty page with status 200) you have to handle an behaviour or remove somewhere the preventdefault()

Comment: Ok, I just saw that, on dev tools network, the post, to the enviar_inscricao.php returns status 200 with 0b in it.

Comment: Check out your ajax-mail.js you trying to display the result in $('.form-messege'); but this element does not exsist.

Answer (score -3):

Either use this url like: "/enviar_inscricao.php " (add a slash to the front),
or enter the full url.

Comment: @RonaldHaan — Why would that help? It isn't being called, so what it does doesn't matter). (And Eva can't. Did you mean to place that comment on the question?)

Comment: `action="enviar_inscricao.php"` and `action="/enviar_inscricao.php"` resolve to the same URL given the starting point is `http://mentores.in/comprar.html`

Comment: @Quentin Because the file exists but does nothing.